# Xcode7 実機デバッグ時のクラッシュエラーについて

Tags: xcode, xcode7, objective-c

初めて質問させていただきます。 
私は現在Xcode7を使用してアプリケーション開発をやっております。 
現在の状態はビルドが通り実機転送してデバッグを行う段階なのですが 
XcodeのRUNボタンを押下するとアプリケーションが一瞬だけ起動しエラーで落ちてしまいます。

エラーは下記画像の箇所にて起きているようです。
[image]

エラーの中身はこのような感じです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラーメッセージ
dyld: malformed mach-o: load commands size (16608) > 16384

下記のことを試してみましたがエラー内容に進展はありませんでした。 
・shift + option + clean 
・preference > Locations > Advanced > Unique→Custom[Relative to Workspace]へ変更 
・General > Deployment info > Deployment Targetの見直し 
・FrameworkのTargetMembershipをRequiredからOptionalへ変更

もし同じ症状で上記以外の方法で解決された方いらっしゃいましたら是非ともご教授いただきたいです。 
至らない点などありましたらコメントで聞いていただければ幸いです。

※追記
OSXのバージョンは10.11です。
iOSのバージョンは9.3です。
DerivedDataの中身を削除も試してみましたがエラー内容に変化はありませんでした。

Comment: DerivedDataの中身を削除してみてはどうでしょう？　あと、実機のOSのバージョンも書いた方が良いかも知れません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通りDerivedDataの中身を削除してみましたがエラー内容に変化なしでした。
OSXのバージョンは10.11を使用しています。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/36197

Comment: エラーメッセージは、「ダイナミックローダー(dyld)なんですけど、ロードしようとしたライブラリのファイル(mach-o形式)が壊れているみたい。commands sizeが１６６０８で、１６３８４を超えてますよ」という事ですから、利用しているライブラリ類をリビルドするなどしてみては如何でしょうか。あるいは、ライブラリのバージョンが異なっているという事も考えれらます。